# Send Header to the source endpoint based on the subscription authentication

Tags: wso2

I am trying to setup a multi-tenancy scenario and I need to submit the tenant key or any tenant identifier as a header to the source endpoint.

So, I have setup an api in the carbon.super tenant and subscribed the same from "tenant1". The subscribed tenant have its own credentials of client id and secret.

When calling the same api from that "tenant1" after the request is authenticated, I need to send the tenant ID or identifier to the end point.

Is this possible to do so ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

same as above mentioned.